# Where is pandas.tools?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

After installing `pandas`:

```
idf:~/Documents/python/plot$ pip3 install pandas --user
Collecting pandas
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f9/e1/4a63ed31e1b1362d40ce845a5735c717a959bda992669468dae3420af2cd/pandas-0.24.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.12.0 in /home/idf/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas) (1.15.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in /home/idf/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas) (2018.7)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.5.0 in /home/idf/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas) (2.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /home/idf/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.5.0->pandas) (1.12.0)
zipline 1.3.0 has requirement pandas<=0.22,>=0.18.1, but you'll have pandas 0.24.0 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: pandas
Successfully installed pandas-0.24.0
idf:~/Documents/python/plot$
```

I try to load `pandas.tools`,

```
from pandas.tools.plotting import autocorrelation_plot

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-e11ce94b8d5d> in <module>
----> 1 from pandas.tools.plotting import autocorrelation_plot


ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.tools'
```

How do I access `pandas.tools`?

Comment: Do you want `tools` or `autocorrelation_plot`? The plotting functions are in `pandas.plotting` now.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#visualization-autocorrelation

Comment: `pandas.tools` has been removed in pandas 1.6.

Answer (score 74):

Package `pandas.tools.plotting` was moved to `pandas.plotting` in [this commit](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/7993fc81098936a893ec0dc0d84d41cfe4eb4218), as part of [#16005](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/16005) and [#12548](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12548) in Pandas `0.20.0`.

More recently, in [this commit](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/398d01717bde0515f7751fa47ebeb73c63c47ce4) in Pandas [#23376](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/23376) released in Pandas `0.24.0`, the deprecated `pandas.tools` package, which was previously allowing `pandas.tools.plotting` to keep working, was removed.

Ergo, once you allow Pandas to upgrade to `0.24.0` or later, you will need to replace imports from `pandas.tools.plotting` to be instead from `pandas.plotting`.

Answer (score 23):

It became `pandas.plotting`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "brod.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pandas.tools.plotting import scatter_matrix
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.tools'
```

This happens in new versions of pandas. This:

```
from pandas.tools.plotting import scatter_matrix
```

is for old versions of pandas. If you are using new versions of pandas, then use this instead:

```
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `pandas.plotting` instead of `pandas.tools.plotting`

Answer (score 0):

According  to the documentation `pands.tools` has been moved to `pandas.core.reshape`.
Further `pandas.plotting`
A new public `pandas.plotting` module has been added that holds plotting functionality that was previously in either `pandas.tools.plotting` or in the top-level namespace.

Documentation : [Link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v0.20.0.html?highlight=tools%20util%20cartesian_product#whatsnew-0200-privacy)