# Pandas: where is autocorrelation_plot?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to plot an `autocorrelation_plot()` of a time series using pandas. 
According to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54473018/where-is-pandas-tools) `pandas.tools` was removed in 0.24.0 and the autocorrelation_plot function can now be found in the `pandas.plotting` library. However the [API](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/plotting.html) shows no reference to this function.

I'm able to plot an autocorrelation by importing the function but where can I find the documentation?

```
from pandas.plotting import autocorrelation_plot # works fine

slope = -1
offset = 250
noise_scale = 100
npts = 100

x = np.linspace(0, 100, npts)
y = slope*x + noise_scale*np.random.rand(npts) + offset

autocorrelation_plot(y)
```

[image: auto_correlation-plot]

**Python:** 3.7.2

**Pandas:** 0.24.1

Comment: Could some advice if this would be a more appropriate [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues) and I could close this thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at:

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.24.1/pandas/plotting/_misc.py#L600

Looks like it was buried in `the plotting._misc` source code.

Comment: This points me in the correct direction, thanks. The doc string was less comprehensive than I was hoping. Should it be included in the [API](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/plotting.html)?

Comment: Seems like a reasonable idea. I think an issue is warranted.  Like most pandas plotting functions, this one accepts `**kwds` and forces you to scour through the matplotlib documentation.  Have a look at: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.acorr.html

Answer (score 2):

I think this would probably be more appropriate as an issue in GitHub.

In any case, `autocorrelation_plot` and the similar plots (`andrews_curves`, `radviz`,...) are probably going to be moved out of pandas, into a separate package. So you can expect to have to call something like `pandas_matplotlib.autocorrelation_plot()` in the future (see [#28177](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/28177)).

In the meantime, I'm adding it and some other missing functions to the documentation in [#28179](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/28179). When the pull request is merged, you'll be able to see the docs in https://dev.pandas.io. But there is nothing very interesting for `autocorrelation_plot`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can at least find a reference and a short doc here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#visualization-autocorrelation

Btw, you can search the docs for any keyword: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/search.html?q=autocorrelation_plot&check_keywords=yes&area=default#